# Finish the proof by induction: Prove $\exists k\in \mathbb Z \Big(\left(11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}\right)=133k\Big)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I've got to prove, by induction, that  $$133\mid (11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1})$$

Basis for this is $n=0;$ So LHS = 133, and RHS = 133;

Assume there exists $k\in \mathbb Z$ $$(11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1})=133k\tag{inductive hypothesis}$$

We should prove that it then follows there exists a $k'\in \mathbb Z$ such $(11^{n+3}+13^{2n+3}) = 133k'$.

What to do with this next?

As I understand, I need to work with $(11^{n+3}+13^{2n+3})$, and try to get k by assumption. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to use the inductive hypothesis (note the label above), to prove that given we have assumed $(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1} = 33 k$, this then implies $$(11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+3}) = \left(11\cdot  11^{n+2} + 12^2\cdot 12^{2n+ 1}\right) = 133k'$$

Comment: Zhyhalo I did my best to track your though process and sequence of statements in my edit above.  If there's anything you'd like to change, let me know, or else feel free to edit yourself.  $\exists k \in \mathbb Z$  simply means there exists an integer k such that (...)

Answer (score 1):

let $$T_n=11^{n+1}+12^{2n+1}$$ and $$T_{n+1}=11^{n+2}+12^{2n+3}$$ then we get
$$T_{n+1}-T_n=(11^{n+1}+12^{2n+1})\cdot 10+133\cdot 12^{2n+1}$$ thus $$133|T_{n+1}$$

Comment: oops, @Dr.Sonnarhard, I deleted my comment once I reread the question again. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to prove that $11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}$ divided by $133$.

I think a proof without induction is better.

Indeed, since $a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+...+b^{n-1}\right)$, we have
$$11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}=121\cdot11^n+12\cdot144^n=12\left(144^n-11^n\right)+133\cdot11^n$$
and we are done!

Comment: For you, dear @amWhy . I fixed my post.